# Is it possible to make Windows search results look like Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

When opening Windows explorer, this generally shows files/directories information using following columns: "Name", "Data modified", "Type" and "Size", and it is possible to sort following those columns.

Using Windows search the results are shown in some kind of table, containing the name, location and size, and the last modification date is shown beneath the name.
Unfortunately it seems, at first glance, not possible to sort those search results (the Windows search results window seems not to have column headers).

Is there a way to make Windows search results look like Windows explorer? (With sortable columns)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, here is how you can do it:

1. Go for a search in some folder
2. Right click in the window where the results are shown -> View -> Details
3. Now you should see the column headers - when you click on one, it will sort down-or upwards.

Hint: When you right click on these columns, you can also add new ones or remove them.

Also take a look here: [How to view full path in search results?](https://superuser.com/questions/616021/how-to-view-full-path-in-search-results)

Comment: Such nice options they made available and such dumb defaults.