# Make windows remember a folder sort setting across sub-folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The solution in this SE answer works but Windows keeps forgetting this setting each time I restart or move to a different folder.

Is there any way to make this setting permenant or a default?

[Sort files by date modified, but folders always before files in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/238825/sort-files-by-date-modified-but-folders-always-before-files-in-windows-explorer)

The goal is the following:

> Is it possible to sort files by date modified, but display directories
> before files?

This is the solution that works well":

> First, put the directory into “Details” view mode (if it isn’t
> already) so you have column headings.
>
> If you click on the “Date Modified” heading, which will sort by Date
> Modified (descending), and then Shift+click on “Name”, it should
> remain sorted by Date Modified (descending), but with the folders at
> the top.

Now the only problem is how does this make this permanent across all folders and saved between restarts.

Is there a batch file etc. that could do this? I was assuming it would be remembered across all sub-folders but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on your comment to [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)'s answer. **Apply to Folders** works on a per-*FolderTYpe* basis, but it's only available to a subset of the defined FolderTypes. To the frustration of many, it's most notably absent from *`Searchesults`* and *`Libraries`*. The `FolderTypes` and their default views are difined in the Registry under:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes`
You can view the comeplete list with this **PowerShell** code:

```
gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes' |
     select @{ N = 'ID'   ; E = { $_.PSChildName } },
            @{ N = 'Name' ; E = { $_.GetValue('CanonicalName') } } |
     Sort Name |
Out-GridView
```

When you execute **Apply to Folders**, A REG_BINARY value named for its associated *FolderType* is created under:
`HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`
This **PowerShell** will list the *FolderTypes* that have a customized default view set by **Apply to Folders**:

```
$Defaults = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'
$FT       = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
( Get-Item $defaults ).Property | ForEach {
     ( gi "$FT\$_" ).GetValue( 'CanonicalName' )
}
```

[ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) has revealed that the `explorer.exe` process only checks the `...Streams\Defaults` key for the following values:

```
ID                                     Name
--                                     ----
{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259} Downloads
{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} Generic
{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656} Documents
{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78} Music
{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239} Pictures
{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8} Videos
{4F01EBC5-2385-41F2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0} StorageProviderGeneric
{DD61BD66-70E8-48DD-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1} StorageProviderDocuments
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247} StorageProviderMusic
{71D642A9-F2B1-42CD-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A} StorageProviderPictures
{51294DA1-D7B1-485B-9E9A-17CFFE33E187} StorageProviderVideos
{DB2A5D8F-06E6-4007-ABA6-AF877D526EA6} AccountPictures
{DE2B70EC-9BF7-4A93-BD3D-243F7881D492} Contacts
{24CCB8A6-C45A-477D-B940-3382B9225668} HomeFolder
{C4D98F09-6124-4FE0-9942-826416082DA9} UsersLibraries
{D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D} Programs
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46E5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3} UserFiles
{0B0BA2E3-405F-415E-A6EE-CAD625207853} Searches
```

So to modify other *FolderTypes*, and avoid the undesireable, brute-force method of modifying the *FolderTypes* under `HKLM`, there are two options.
Both involve creating registry entires that don't exist by default -- which means reversing the edits is a simple matter of deletion.

One option is to create GUID-named subkeys under:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell`
and creating these is the simplest method if you only want to change the icon mode, for example, setting `SearchResults` to `Details` rather than `Content`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004
```

But because these entries use the same format as the individual folder views saved under `HKCU\...\Bags`, they don't lend themselves to modifying default columns, sortBy, or GroupBy specifications as those are rather cryptic binary values:

```
    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local
    Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\116\Shell


Name                           Property
----                           --------
{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF4 Rev              : 2
6979D49}                       FFlags           : 1090519041
                               Vid              :
                               {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}
                               Mode             : 4
                               LogicalViewMode  : 1
                               IconSize         : 16
                               Sort             : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                               ColInfo          : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                               GroupView        : 4294967295
                               GroupByKey:FMTID :
                               {23620678-CCD4-47C0-9963-95A8405678A3}
                               GroupByKey:PID   : 100
                               GroupByDirection : 1
```

So to modify those, it's easier to go with the other option: creating a copy of `HKLM\...\FOlderTypes` under `HKCU`. When these entries exist, they override the `HKLM` values.

With these copies, you can modify the various values found under the varous GUID-named *TopViews*, which lend thesmselves more readily to human reading/editing:

```
{dfbd6ba3-1846-438f-8675-b65a6bd9d418} ColumnList      : prop:0System.ItemNameDisplay;0S
                                       ystem.ItemDate;0System.ItemTypeText;0Sy
                                                         stem.Size;0System.Media.Duratio
                                       n;0System.ItemFolderPathDisplay;1System
                                                         .DateCreated;1System.DateModifi
                                       ed;1System.Search.Rank;1System.Media.Da
                                                         teEncoded;1System.Image.Dimensi
                                       ons;2System.Video.FrameWidth;2System.Vi
                                                         deo.FrameHeight
                                       LogicalViewMode : 1
                                       Name            : @shell32.dll,-34839
                                       Order           : 7
                                       QueryType       : 1
                                       SortByList      : prop:System.ItemNameDisplay
```

You'd be wanting to edit the `SortByList` values for the various `TopViews`, here's a rundown of their defaults:

```
PS C:\...\Mirror-Folder>$rp.ft | gci |
>>  ? { $_.GetValue('CanonicalName') -match 'SearchResults$' } |
>>        gci -Recurse | ? PSChildName -like '{*}' | gp |
>>              select @{ N = 'LVM'        ; E = { $_.LogicalVIewMode }},
>>                     @{ N = 'FolderTYpe' ; E = { ( Split-Path $_.PSParentPath | gp ).CanonicalName  }},
>>                     @{ N = 'ArrangeBy'  ; E = { gls $_.Name }},
>>                     SortByList |
>> ft -AutoSize -Wrap

LVM FolderTYpe                   ArrangeBy     SortByList
--- ----------                   ---------     ----------
  1 Contacts.SearchResults       Name          prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  1 Contacts.SearchResults       Folder        prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  1 Contacts.SearchResults       Category      prop:System.Category;-System.DateModifie
                                               d
  5 Documents.SearchResults      Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  5 Documents.SearchResults      Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 Documents.SearchResults      Tag           prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  5 Documents.SearchResults      Type          prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  5 Documents.SearchResults      Author        prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  5 OtherUsers.SearchResults     Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 OtherUsers.SearchResults     Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  5 Pictures.SearchResults       Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  3 Pictures.SearchResults       Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.ItemDat
                                               e;System.ItemNameDisplay
  3 Pictures.SearchResults       Rating        prop:-System.ItemDate;System.ItemNameDis
                                               play
  3 Pictures.SearchResults       Tag           prop:-System.ItemDate;System.ItemNameDis
                                               play
  3 Pictures.SearchResults       Day           prop:+System.ItemDate;System.ItemNameDis
                                               play
  3 Pictures.SearchResults       Month         prop:-System.ItemDate;System.ItemNameDis
                                               play
  5 Communications.SearchResults Top results   prop:System.Contact.FileAsName;-System.M
                                               essage.DateReceived;-System.Search.Rank
  5 UsersLibraries.SearchResults Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 UsersLibraries.SearchResults Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  5 Music.SearchResults          Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  1 Music.SearchResults          Song          prop:System.Music.Artist;System.Music.Al
                                               bumTitle;System.Music.TrackNumber;System
                                               .Title
  5 Music.SearchResults          Genre         prop:System.Music.Artist;System.Music.Al
                                               bumTitle;System.Music.TrackNumber;-Syste
                                               m.DateModified
  5 Music.SearchResults          Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 Music.SearchResults          Rating        prop:System.Music.Artist;System.Music.Al
                                               bumTitle;System.Music.TrackNumber
  5 Music.SearchResults          Artist        prop:System.Music.Artist;System.Music.Al
                                               bumTitle;System.Music.TrackNumber;-Syste
                                               m.DateModified
  5 Music.SearchResults          Album         prop:System.Music.Artist;System.Music.Al
                                               bumTitle;System.Music.TrackNumber;-Syste
                                               m.DateModified
  5 Generic.SearchResults        Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 Generic.SearchResults        Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  5 PublishedItems.SearchResults Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;System.ItemName
                                               Display;-System.DateModified
  5 PublishedItems.SearchResults Date modified prop:-System.Search.Rank;System.ItemName
                                               Display;-System.DateModified
  5 UserFiles.SearchResults      Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  5 UserFiles.SearchResults      Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.DateMod
                                               ified;System.ItemNameDisplay
  3 Videos.SearchResults         Top results   prop:-System.Search.Rank;-System.ItemDat
                                               e;System.ItemNameDisplay
  3 Videos.SearchResults         Year          prop:+System.ItemDate;System.ItemNameDis
                                               play
  5 Videos.SearchResults         Date modified prop:-System.DateModified
  3 Videos.SearchResults         Type          prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;-System.Date
                                               Modified
  2 Videos.SearchResults         Length        prop:-System.Media.Duration
  1 Videos.SearchResults         Name          prop:System.ItemNameDisplay
```

The `Arrange By>` options are available for `SearchResult`s folders when the search is initiated from a *Library*:
[image]

****This answer in progress...nedd some sleep...

Comment: Great info. Look forward to the rest of the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

To apply the current folder's view and sort order to all folders:

- Go to the *View* pane
- Click on *Options > Change folder and search options*
- Go to the *View* Tab
- Click on *Apply to Folders*

Comment: Looks like this works! Thanks. Is there a way to apply this to the files that show up when I use the search box in windows file explorer as well?

Comment: Search results need separate formatting that is supposed to "stick". See [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1245790/is-it-possible-to-make-windows-search-results-look-like-windows-explorer).

Answer (score 0):

The free app [WinSetView](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView/) will let you globally set all default folder views, including Libraries and Search results. It applies the same HKCU FolderTypes registry values that are noted in Keith Miller's answer.